# SharePoint 2019 Installation Error - NoComponentID

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, 2019, autospinstaller

I am installing a SharePoint 2019 on a single server for development purposes. I am using [AutoSPInstaller](https://autospinstaller.com) to do the install. After running that application and the installation completes, I can successfully view central admin and mysites. Howerver going to the default site (ie contoso.com), I get a NoComponentID error. Looking at the ULS log file doesn't provide any details as to what is causing this issue. Googling online, I haven't seen any solutions to this error when it happens after a fresh install. Initially I thought it was because of the site template selected (ie Modern Team Site or Communication Site) but no matter what site template I use, I get the same error. Can someone please help me with this? I have spent days trying to figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: I got the very same issue also using AutoSPInstaller to create the site collection using communication template. Is deleting and recreating the only solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error, do the following:

1. Go to Central Admin -> Application Management -> Site Collections -> Delete a site collection
2. In the dialog that appears, make sure you select the correct web application and then select the root URL
3. Click OK to confirm the selection
4. This will bring you to the confirmation screen. Click Delete if you are sure you have selected the right site.
5. Next go to Create site collections to create a new site. Make sure the path select displays the forward slash symbol /

Now the new site will operate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around with PowerShell, the problem is that for Modern sites to work, they need Client Application Page Id column to appear in the Site Pages library. Unfortunately this column was not being created during the install. To correct this issue, I developed the following PowerShell script to add the missing column.

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
  Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL
$Ctx = Get-PnPContext
$List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages")
$Ctx.Load($List.Fields)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
# Add missing column
Add-PnpField -list 'Site Pages' -DisplayName 'Client Application Page Id' -InternalName 'ClientSideApplicationId'-Type Guid
```

I hope this helps others that encounter this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the fix mentioned above does not fix all the issues. While it does allow the page to be displayed, you can't edit it nor create new pages on the site. See my answer below to truly fix this issue.